# Sample Pandas Dataframe with equal number based on binary column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with a `data` column, and a `value` column, as in the example below. The `value` column is always binary, 0 or 1:

```
data,value
173,1
1378,0
926,0
643,0
1279,0
472,0
706,0
1345,0
1167,1
1401,1
1236,0
447,1
1204,1
398,0
714,0
734,0
1732,0
98,0
1696,0
160,0
1611,0
274,1
562,0
625,0
1028,0
1766,0
511,0
1691,0
898,1
```

I need to sample the dataset so that basically *I have an equal number of both values*. So, if I originally have less `1` class, I'll need to use that one as a reference. In turn, if I have less `0` classes, I need to use that.

Any clues on how to do this? I'm working on a jupyter notebook, Python 3.6 (I cannot go up versions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Sample data

```py
data = [173,926,634,706,398]
value = [1,0,0,1,0]

df = pd.DataFrame({"data": data, "value": value})

print(df)

# data  value 
# 0   173      1
# 1   926      0
# 2   634      0
# 3   706      1
# 4   398      0
```

#### Filter to two DFs

```py
ones = df[df['value'] == 1]
zeros = df[df['value'] == 0]

print(ones)
print()
print()
print(zeros)

# data  value 
# 0   173      1
# 3   706      1


# data  value 
# 1   926      0
# 2   634      0
# 4   398      0
```

#### Truncate as required

Find the minimum and then truncate it (take `n` first rows)

```py
if len(ones) <= len(zeros):
  zeros = zeros.iloc[:len(ones), :]
else:
  ones = ones.iloc[:len(zeros), :]

print(ones)
print()
print()
print(zeros)

# data  value 
# 0   173      1
# 3   706      1
#
#
# data  value 
# 1   926      0
# 2   634      0
```

Comment: I think the only reason would be that this isn't a true *sampling* method. Sampling would mean you need to randomly select from the larger group, not just take the first n rows.

Answer (score 1):

Group your dataframe by values, and then take a sample of the smallest count from each group.

```
grouped = df.groupby(['value'])
smallest = grouped.count().min().values
try: # Pandas 1.1.0+
   print(grouped.sample(smallest))
except AttributeError: # Pre-Pandas 1.1.0
   print(grouped.apply(lambda df: df.sample(smallest)))
```

Output:

```
    data  value
25  1766      0
3    643      0
10  1236      0
1   1378      0
14   714      0
6    706      0
24  1028      0
8   1167      1
9   1401      1
0    173      1
12  1204      1
11   447      1
28   898      1
21   274      1
```

Comment: With this one, I get the following error: `AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'sample' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method`. It may be because I am using Python 3.6 ?

Comment: @Carrol it works for me. What version is your pandas? `groupby.sample` became available since pandas 1.1.0

Comment: This, I understand that you're fixed with python 3.6, but can you upgrade pandas? `pip install --upgrade pandas`

Comment: So `pip show pandas` told me `0.19.2`, and when I ran `pip install -- upgrade pandas` it said `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement upgrade (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for upgrade`

Comment: @Carrol Okay, I added an additional check and the code for how to do it on your version of pandas:

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

```
df.groupby('value').sample(df.groupby('value').size().min())
```